# Add project member only to Firebase (not whole Google Cloud)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

We have a Google Cloud project and a Firebase project associated with it. I need to add a mobile app developer to the Firebase project, but I don't want them to access the entire Google Cloud platform, which is also used by our website.

Does Firebase has a way to add a new member only to Firebase, minus other Google Cloud services?

Closest IAM roles I found were Firebase Test Lab Admin/Viewer and Firebase Crash Symbol Uploader, but there appears to be no role for Firebase as a whole... am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Doug in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52118801/8831875), Firebase project and Google Cloud Project are the same entity. Indeed, the only way to limit the member's interaction to just Firebase part is by assigning him desired roles or maybe [creating a custom one](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles).